# Have random point cloud randomnly distributed per instance using same geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have an issue and I couldn't find any relevant resource that is helpful.

The objective is to have random point cloud randomnly distributed per instance using same geometry nodes. If I remove the Configurable Named Attribute (Seed) which is set manually per instance [0, 3], then I get the same distribution per istance which is visible when the density is low. I want to avoid using such methods (the one metioned above, rotating the instances and so on) and I'm wondering if there is an input (instance integer-based) which can be supplied to the seed such that the method will scale better with (3 and more instances)?

Any other solutions are helpful as well. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3.4 there is a Self Object node, that you can use to get the position of the object. Using that, you can generate different seeds for each object in space:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible something similar to this solution but using a lower version (e.g., 3.3.1)?

Comment: Yes, add empty object and use it instead of self object node, object info in relative mode. In this case distance to empty will be counted, it is quite similar.

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you @Crantisz